# Elastic search phrase exact match without analysing

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search

Current elastic mapping:

```
"properties": {
"content": {
    "type": "text",
       "term_vector":"with_positions_offsets",
     "fields": {
         "keyword": {                
             "type": "keyword",
             "ignore_above": 256
         }
    },
     "analyzer": "russian"
   }        
}
```

Field "content" contains results of site crawling, exactly pages "body" tag content, stripped off from tags. 
Task is to realize three types of search for this field. 
1. All specified words
2. Any of the specified words
3. Exactly in the text

For 1 case - match_phrase 
For 2 case - match
For 3 case - there must be match_phrase without analizing, becouse with "russian" analizer it finds this phraze with different endings and declensions

Tried this query with no luck:

```
"query": {
"bool": {
    "must": [
     {
      "match_phrase": {   
           "content":  {
               "query": "some search phraze",
       "analyzer": "keyword"
        }
       }
     }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For `exact` match query use `Term Query`. So your query should look like below:

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "term" : { "content.keyword" : "some search phraze" } 
  }
}
```

Comment: No results found. Hits = 0

Comment: can you provide some sample document?

Comment: It is kilobytes of text. It cold be hundred words or few thousands.

Comment: Can you illustrate what are you trying to achieve with some example?

Answer (score 0):

Self answering

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30520285/1235390) answer helped me a lot

Adding extra field "raw" to property solved problem.

```
"properties": {
    "content": {
        "type": "text",
        "term_vector":"with_positions_offsets",
        "fields": {
            "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
            },
            "raw": {
                "type": "text",
                "index": "analyzed"
            }
        },
    "analyzer": "russian"
    }        
}
```

search query looks like this:

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [
             {
                 "match_phrase": {   
                     "content.raw":  {
                          "query": "some search phraze",
                     }
                 }
             }
         ]
    }
```